# Is there a clean way to access a child components ng-model value which is within a directive in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Basically what happens is that I have a structure in the code like this:

```
<someCustomDirective>
      <myCustomComponent />
</someCustomDirective>
```

myCustomComponent is a input which  internally has a ng-model, and I want to use the values of that input cause of irelevant reasons, in the directive, so basically I need to push up the current value of the myCustomComponent ng-model, and have it available in the someCustomDirective.

The thing is scope is not working exactly as expected, and emits also, cause first the component gets created and then the wrapping directive.

How is it possible in simple fashion to get the value of the underlying child component?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via callback inside your controller that you access via scope in the directive, have a good one!